# Передача показаний с датчика по bluetooth на Андройд устройство

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth

Необходимо получить показания влажности и температуры с датчика DHT12. Схема состоит из Arduino + DHT12 + HC-06 (блютус модуль). У меня получилось выводить список устройств и подключиться к Arduino.

Код для Arduino и код MainActivity.java:

```
#include <DHT12.h>

DHT12 dht12;

void setup() {
dht12.begin();
Serial.begin(9600);
delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  int status = dht12.read();
  switch (status)   {
  case DHT12_OK:
  Serial.println(F("Status : OK"));
  
  Serial.print(F("T = "));
  Serial.print(dht12.getTemperature());
  Serial.println(F("*C"));

  Serial.print(F("H = "));
  Serial.print(dht12.getHumidity());
  Serial.println(F(" %"));
  break;
case DHT12_ERROR_CHECKSUM:
  Serial.print(F("Checksum error"));
  break;
case DHT12_ERROR_CONNECT:
  Serial.print(F("Connect error"));
  break;
case DHT12_MISSING_BYTES:
  Serial.print(F("Missing bytes"));
  break;
default:
  Serial.print(F("Unknown error"));
  break;
  }
  delay(2000);
  }
```

---

```
@Override
public void run() { // Приём данных

    while (true) {
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            int bytes = connectedInputStream.read(buffer);
            String strIncom = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
            sb.append(strIncom); // собираем символы в строку
            int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n"); // определяем конец строки
            } catch (IOException e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите передать или получить даныне по Bluetooth - смотрите в сторону GATT протокола, BLE и оформляйте это все в foreground сервисе. Вообще удивительно, что текущее решение работает - это как пытаться сделать ракету из мусора по дворе))

https://www.bluetooth.com/ Здесь можно найти все-возможные примеры в том числе для вас, удачи)